# Заменяемость "висит" и "свисает"

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

Всегда ли нечто с чего-то свисает? Нельзя ли говорить "нечто с того-то висит"?

Без примеров обойдёмся? Или нужны? Ну, скажем, "бельё висит с балкона" это нормативно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примеров немного, но встречаются. Определить корректность помогает контекст;  без колебаний фрагменты приведённых фраз можно назвать корректными.

> Я висел с левого крыла мостика... (Виктор Конецкий. Вчерашние заботы, > 1979)
>
> Вадим с непонятным спокойствием рассматривал речные травы и густой хмель, который яркими, зелеными кудрями висел с глинистого  берега. (Лермонтов М.Ю., Вадим, 1833-1834)
>
> На месте большого колокола в этой беседке довольно часто в летнюю пору висел с перекладины человечий скелет... (Ф. И. Буслаев. Мои воспоминания, 1897)
>
> Он смотрел довольно долго и понял: балки висели с крыши... (Ю. Н.
>   Тынянов. Смерть Вазир-Мухтара, 1928)